# Android NDK - building native libraries without Android Studio

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm working on a c/c++ cross-platform project, constructed of 2 main libraries (with a few external dependencies: ssl, yajl, fribidi).
The android solution will include Java files and a JNI layer, all bundled in a AAR file (including assets and the native libs).

I managed to build the whole project, but in a very awkward way:
I created a 'hello world' Android app', with native support, from within Android Studio, and added all native dependencies to the CMAkeList.txt. I added my Java code + JNI and managed to create the AAR (only for ARM, for now).

Now I need to separate the build of the different libraries, to their separate projects, respectively: libA, libB and C.aar.

**How is it done without the IDE (and via command-line)?**
There's the **stand-alone NDK**, the **make_standalone_toolchain.py** script, **android.toolchain.cmake** and other options, but none are documented or up-to-date. Most documentation still talks about the outdated Android.mk methodology.
I'd presume including   **android.toolchain.cmake** in my CMakeList.txt, which will set all needed environment...

I'm using the newest Android Studio 3.0.1 and NDK r16b (installed via SDK Manager)

Alex - thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Just had to add a few flags and a call to make:

```
> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=%ANDROID_NDK%\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-19 -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=%ANDROID_NDK%\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_ABI="armeabi-v7a with NEON" ..
> cmake --build .
```

Comment: Instead of `make`, it's cleaner to use `cmake --build`. *directory* is an optional parameter. This way you don't need to worry about the choice of *generator*. Maybe **Ninja** will work fatster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio (the standard Android gradle plugin, that is) does not support native-only modules, but you can split your CMake script and work with **libA** and **libB** separately. You can run **cmake** from command line (but better use the version that is shipped with Android SDK).

```
sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake ...
```

The easiest way to build the AAR file that includes a compiled Java wrapper and the two native libraries would be with Android Studio, but you can run the gradle task from command line. This is what we typically do on a build server.

Comment: Does it matter whether we use CMake bundled with SDK or a standard one from APT repository?

Comment: @Quest as I wrote, to be on the safe side, you may prefer the bundled cmake. It was verified by Google to work correctly with their toolchain file.